# iOS capture selection on segment control

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I am new to iOS and iPhone development using MonoTouch.  I have a UIViewController and in XCode I have placed a segment controller with 2 choices on my view.  I have a couple of questions.

1. What sort of connection should I make with the Segment Control in XCode?
2. How can I capture the response in my view controller?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

First, since you are new to iOS. I would recommend you to NOT use Monotouch, not because i think it is bad. But if you do it directly with Xcode and Objective-C you can learn the underlying plumbings of the code. I say this because sometimes MonoTouch could throw errors which would seem obvious to developers who work natively on the Objective-C level.

That being said, the `UISegmentedControl` is wired up the same was as you did with almost every other control in iOS.

(Assuming you are using storyboard with ARC)

Drag a `UISegmentedControl` onto the view you want. I will also assume you have a class associated with the view controller. Something like the screenshot below, where the left is the `ViewController` and the right is my class associated with it (ignore the naming, i just took a screen of something i am working on right now)

[image: UIViewController image]

To wire up the segmented control, have the following code inside your `ViewController.h` file:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
```

And then synthesize them inside your `ViewController.m` file:

```
@synthesize segmentedControl;
```

Your storyboard should have something like the screenshot below. Note, the value in the Referencing Outlets.

[image: Segmented Control]

With all the wiring setup, you could now do different stuff. Example screenshot is shown below:

[image: Segmented Control Options.]

Comment: I disagree about not using MT if you are new to iOS. The whole value proposition of MT is not having to learn ObjC. Google is always useful if you don't understand the error (which is what you would do anyway if you were using XCode and didn't understand the error...)

Comment: Well, I kinda read the Docs. But that is just me and to each their own, i suppose.

Comment: Very true about 'each to their own' (Good answer btw +1).